# Running a react app in docker : react app in docker fails to run

Tags: reactjs, docker

I am trying to run a react app in a docker image however it exits without an error message

DokerFile

```html
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD npm start --port 3000
```

then I proceeded to build

```
docker build -t react-app:latest .
```

then I run

```
docker run -p 7000:3000 react-app:latest
```

gives the following out put

[image]

then exits out

this is what I see on the browser

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your docker closes because the tty is not enabled.
In order to work, you have to run the docker with

```
docker run -t -p 7000:3000 react-app:latest
```

For more info: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688

But this should be only for testing/development. In production you should build your react app and then serve it with serve or with nginx

Comment: I am trying to run the -d option to run in the background it doesnt seem to be working any advise?

Comment: run it using `docker run -tid`